# custom registry - why only package.json extracted?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-registry

For security reasons I need to setup a custom npm-registry.

I configure a local http-registry (nginx) using this command:

```
npm config set @example:registry=http://localhost/
```

Then I place two files to nginx

```
.
..
@example%2fmodel
model.tgz
```

The contents of `@example%2fmodel` is:

```
{
  "name":"Model", 
  "dist-tags":{"foo":"1.0.0"},
  "versions":{
    "1.0.0":{
      "version":"1.0.0", 
      "dist":{"tarball":"model.tgz"}
    }
  }
}
```

The content of `model.tgz` is the `package.json` and the `Model.ts`.

The the `Model.ts` (from tarball) is:

```
export const URL = 'https://example.com/';
export const USER = 'apiv2';
export const PASS = '***';
```

The `package.json` (from tarball) is:

```
{"name":"Model","version":"1.0.0","files":"*.ts"}
```

As you can see, its all minimal and all straightforward.

Then I do a:

```
npm install @example/model
added 1 package in 0.347s
npm info ok
```

That worked well. But my `Model.ts` is missing

[image]

Comment: does the problem persist after removing the `files` attribute from the `package.json` file?

Comment: @MfyDev yes, it persist.

Comment: @Grim Can you confirm your directory structure, where is the .ts file in relation to your package.json and where the tgz gets created

Comment: In the same root of the tgz. In the tgz is no directory, just two files in root:  `package.json` and `Model.ts`. Just start yourself a webserver and serve the files, so you can reproduce the problem very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I solved it myself,

I had to create a subdirectory called `package` in the tgz.
And the main must be a ecmascript-file.